# How to make the size of the last column of QTableWidget equal to the others

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I wanted to make a table that the size (width and height) of items inside the list to be equal. But the width of the last column is not the same as the others (it has been stretched)

I've used the setFixedSize to change the size, maybe that's the problem.

See this picture:
[image: See this picture]

This is my code:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QHeaderView, QTableWidget, QWidget

# Main Window
class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "PyQt5 - QTableWidget"
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 100
        self.width = 740
        self.height = 880
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.createTable()

    def createTable(self):
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget(self)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(8)
        self.tableWidget.setFixedSize(700, 700)
        self.tableWidget.move(100, 100)

        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)

        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView.Stretch)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Remove the two `setStretchLastSection(True)` lines. Then all the sections will stretch equally to fill the available space. Otherwise, all but the last section will be squeezed down to the default section size.

Comment: @ekhumoro thank you! this solved my problem